# How to check if Y coordinates of mouse is greater than a value

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouse, coordinates

I can check the Y coordinates of mouse through this.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var MouseY = "( " + event.clientY + " )";
});
```

But how to trigger a function when it is greater than a value, say 20px. I guess this one is not working

```
if (MouseY > 20){
  alert('yes');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't combine both of your snippets?

```
$(document).mousemove(function() {
  var threshold = 20;
  if(event.clientY > threshold) {
    alert('Current mouse position is: ' + event.clientY);
    // or call another function here like: 
    // react(event.clientY);
  };
});
```

Is this what you wanted?